# How to roll window using future values instead of past values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Pandas seems to use previous rows instead of the next rows when it creates rolling windows. To illustrate, I will use this data:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range('2022-01-01', '2022-01-07'),
    'num': [20, 27, 19, 23, 24, 26, 21],
}).set_index('date')
```

```
            num
date           
2022-01-01   20
2022-01-02   27
2022-01-03   19
2022-01-04   23
2022-01-05   24
2022-01-06   26
2022-01-07   21
```

I am trying to create a new column that for each day, calculates the maximum percentage increase of the next two days relative to that day. For example, on `2022-01-01`, within a window of the next two days, the number has increased from `20` to `27`, which is a 35% increase. This is the code:

```py
df['max_increase'] = df['num'].rolling(3).apply(
    lambda xs: max(xs[1:] - xs[0]) / xs[0]
)
```

```
            num  max_increase
date                         
2022-01-01   20           NaN
2022-01-02   27           NaN
2022-01-03   19      0.350000
2022-01-04   23     -0.148148
2022-01-05   24      0.263158
2022-01-06   26      0.130435
2022-01-07   21      0.083333
```

However, that is not what I want. I do not want the `NaN` values. I want the 35% increase (i.e. `0.350000`) to be associated with `2022-01-01`, not with `2022-01-03`. Note that `df['max_increase'] = df['max_increase'].shift(-2)` will not fix the problem, since it will produce `NaN` values for the last two rows. This is what I want:

```
            num  max_increase
date                         
2022-01-01   20      0.350000  # Increase from 20 to 27.
2022-01-02   27     -0.148148  # Decrease from 27 to 23.
2022-01-03   19      0.263158  # Increase from 19 to 24.
2022-01-04   23      0.130435  # Increase from 23 to 26.
2022-01-05   24      0.083333  # Increase from 24 to 26.
2022-01-06   26     -0.192307  # Decrease from 26 to 21.
2022-01-07   21      0.000000
```

It appears the the problem stems from the rolling windows that Pandas created. It appears that Pandas created these 3-day windows using  previous rows instead of future rows:

- `2022-01-01`
- `2022-01-01`, `2022-01-02`
- `2022-01-01`, `2022-01-02`, `2022-01-03`
- `2022-01-02`, `2022-01-03`, `2022-01-04`
- `2022-01-03`, `2022-01-04`, `2022-01-05`
- `2022-01-04`, `2022-01-05`, `2022-01-06`
- `2022-01-05`, `2022-01-06`, `2022-01-07`

How do I make Pandas create a forward rolling window instead? i.e.

- `2022-01-01`, `2022-01-02`, `2022-01-03`
- `2022-01-02`, `2022-01-03`, `2022-01-04`
- `2022-01-03`, `2022-01-04`, `2022-01-05`
- `2022-01-04`, `2022-01-05`, `2022-01-06`
- `2022-01-05`, `2022-01-06`, `2022-01-07`
- `2022-01-06`, `2022-01-07`
- `2022-01-07`

Comment: @FirefightingPhysicist The code in the question is only a simple example to illustrate the problem. In my real code, the window could be large (e.g. 200) and variable. It is not practical to calculate by hand.

Comment: Okay, I was just about to suggest the method of mozway with inverting it using `.iloc[::-1]` and setting `min_periods=1`. I was just wondering about why you do not want to use `shift` in the process

Answer (score 0):

Use a shifted rolling max:

```
df['max_increase'] = (df.loc[::-1, 'num']
                        .rolling(3, min_periods=1)
                        .apply(lambda x: x.shift().max())
                        .sub(df['num'])
                        .div(df['num']).fillna(0)
                     )
```

output:

```
            num  max_increase
date                         
2022-01-01   20      0.350000
2022-01-02   27     -0.148148
2022-01-03   19      0.263158
2022-01-04   23      0.130435
2022-01-05   24      0.083333
2022-01-06   26     -0.192308
2022-01-07   21      0.000000
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Could you add some explanations for the code, and how you came up with it?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to append the last two rows to the original dataframe and shifting the results (after applying `rolling`) afterwards:

```
n = 3  # window size

df['max_increase'] = (pd.concat([df, pd.concat([df[-1:]]*(n-1))])['num']
    .rolling(n).apply(lambda xs: max(xs[1:] - xs[0]) / xs[0])
    .shift(-(n-1)).dropna())
```

Output:

```
            num  max_increase
date                         
2022-01-01   20      0.350000
2022-01-02   27     -0.148148
2022-01-03   19      0.263158
2022-01-04   23      0.130435
2022-01-05   24      0.083333
2022-01-06   26     -0.192308
2022-01-07   21      0.000000
```